# How to specify the geometry of the *tex-shell* frame?

Tags: latex, frames, ubuntu

I'm using Emacs 24 in Ubuntu 14.04 and when first compiling a TeX file after start up, a frame called `*tex-shell*` is automatically opened and all further compilation processes run in this frame.

I usually move this frame to another workspace ("desktop"), so my editing appears in my main workspace and compilation in a secondary one.

It would be optimal if this new frame appeared directly in this secondary workspace, but I presume that this is kinda difficult. In any case,

> I would like to know if there is a way of choosing the geometry of the frame, in the sense that it has the same size and the same position in the screen every time.

Actually, it seems that the geometry is always the same, but when I changed from Emacs 23 to Emacs 24 this parameter changed.

Thank you for any help, and specially if you know something about automatically selecting workspaces.

Comment: I can't help you with Linux workspaces, but Emacs can control most aspects of frames:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Size-and-Position.html  E.g., `set-frame-size`, `set-frame-position`.  The initial frame can be controlled with the `initial-frame-alist`, and subsequent frames can be controlled with the `default-frame-alist`.  The function `make-frame` accepts parameters to control frame aspects.  Emacs 25 contains substantial bug fixes relating to frame creation, sizing, etc. -- so you should upgrade from Emacs 24 if the frame-related stuff is not behaving properly

Comment: To control which buffer displays in which frame, here is a link to a complex example that works for non-file-visiting-buffers such as `*tex-shell*` and also file-visiting-buffers --  "**How to intercept a file before it opens and decide which frame**":  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346785/how-to-intercept-a-file-before-it-opens-and-decide-which-frame

Comment: @lawlist Thanks; I'll try to make this work. If it does, maybe you could post your advice as an answer.